# C#: get the value of a key in an object using regex

Tags: c#

I have a key with random bits of string in it making it difficult to extract it's value. How would I go about doing it when I don't know the random bits ahead of time?

given:

```
sample = {\"total_ra4jhga987y3h_power\": 30}
```

Is it possible to do something directly like

```
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(sample);
obj[@"^total_(.*)_power$"] ---> should give me 30
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use LINQ to JSON instead. If you parse it as a `JObject`, you can iterate over all the properties, and find those which match your regex.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(...);
JObject json = JObject.Parse(text);
foreach (var property in json.Properties())
{
    if (regex.IsMatch(property.Name))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to do Properties(); isntead of GetProperties and it worked using Newtonsoft.Json

Answer (score 2):

```
var jsonDict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,long>>(sample);
Regex rg = new Regex("total_.*_power");
var key = jsonDict.Keys.First(k=>rg.IsMatch(k));
Console.log(jsonDict[key]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize LINQ to go through your properties and test their names for your regexp:

```
public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static Dictionary<string, JToken> PropertiesByRegexp(this JObject token, Regex regex)
    {
        return token.Properties()
            .Where(p => regex.IsMatch(p.Name))
            .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.Value);
    }
}
```

You can now use this extensions method in the following way:

```
JObject sample = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{\"total_ra4jhga987y3h_power\": 30, \"not_matching\": 31}") as JObject;

var result = sample.PropertiesByRegexp(new Regex("^total_(.*)_power$"));

foreach (var propertyPair in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{propertyPair.Key}: {propertyPair.Value}");
}
```

Outputs:

> total_ra4jhga987y3h_power: 30